# Is this problem correct that $HG'=G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Here, I have the following homework:

> Let $G$ is a finite $p-$group and let $H$ be a subgroup of it such that $HG'=G$. Prove that $H=G$ ($G'$ is the commutator subgroup).

I have tried to show that $G\subseteq H$ by taking an element in $G$ but this way seems to be weak here. Is it possible that this exercise is printed mistakenly? Thank you friends.

Comment: This is in fact true for any nilpotent group, finite or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It suffices to prove that $G'$ is a subgroup of $\Phi(G)$, the Frattini subgroup of $G$.  In the case of $p$-groups, you can do this by showing that $G/\Phi(G)$ is elementary abelian.  (This is actually true for nilpotent groups in general, in which case $G/\Phi(G)$ just has to be abelian, though not necessarily elementary.)

Comment: Thank you but as far as I know, we have always $G/\Phi(G)$ is an elementary abelian when $G$ is a $p-$ group. How is it linked to your first claim that is a famous lemma and is a way for proving this problem?

Comment: This is an excellent answer.
However, I'd like to add an explanation just in case.
Suppose $H \neq G$.
There exists a maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$ containing $H$.
Since $M \supset \Phi(G) \supset G'$, $M \supset HG'$.
This is a contradiction.

Comment: @MakotoKato: Yes!. I got the point. Thanks both of you.